# Won't connect via LTE

Tags: internet, 7.1-nougat, oneplus-5

Now my phone can't use internet with 4G. An exclamation mark appears near the signal bars. Although there's a speed indicator it won't down or up load anything. But I can surf on 3G (when 2G/3G is chosen as the preferred network type) without any problem. How to use 4G like before?

[image]

Comment: So you used to surf on 4g normally with that phone and that sim card? Did you installed any OTA system updates in time when that problem appeared?

Comment: Yes, and, well, that two incidents have about a 3 days' gap

Comment: It's not due to update, probably. I see you solved problem, neat.

Comment: Then what caused it?

Comment: And again the exclamation mark showed up but nothing seems to affect the connection.

Comment: Check again settings you have changed previously, call your carrier help center maybe is up to them.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what happened but, when the "APN protocol" and "APN roaming protocol" are set to IPv4/IPv6 from IPv4, all the problems went away.